# Where to download IIS5.1

Tags: windows-xp, installation, iis

Where I can download IIS 5.1?

Comment: When you asked Microsoft, what did they say?

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.iisanswers.com/IISFAQ.htm?

Answer (score 1):

IIS 5.1 is part of XP pro and Windows 2000 and comes with the install media. It is not available to the newer platforms (Vista, Windows 7, Server 2003/2008).

In order to install it, go to "Add Remove Programs" on the control panel, select "Windows components" and then make sure IIS is selected.

Comment: The XP disc is required.

Comment: That's what I meant by "install media". It is the media (CD) that windows XP is installed from. So yes, the XP cd is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  It's only for Windows 2000, and ships on the Windows 2000 media and service packs.

Choose Add/Remove Windows Components in your Windows 2000 installation.  If you have a version of Windows greater than Windows 2000, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is bundled with Windows XP Professional (if you are using Windows XP Professional).

Else, visit Microsoft IIS site (http://www.iis.net/)

Comment: Yes i know but, I don't have the disc..